# How to incorporate a custom directive into angular's validation framework

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is designed to be assigned to a normal text input.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fooModel" foo-input size="30"
       placeholder="insert value"></input>
```

I have lots of validation functions for it like testing the precision of the numbers and I use a $parsers to control the value that is submitted.

```
myApp.directive('fooInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                        this.errorMessage = ""
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl)

         return ctrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                var originalVal = element.val();


                if (!testForOverPrecision(numericVal)) {
                    //do something here to set the directive as invalid
                }

                if (originalVal != inputValue) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(res);
                    ctrl.$render();
                }
            });
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get this to work with the isValid service and do I have to have a controller scope for the error message
2. Is it correct for me to push the $parser inside a `return` statement

Comment: if you are using (or can use) angular 1.3 the whole validation API just got a huge improvement and simplification. Makes exactly what you are doing a lot cleaner see: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html The video is very helpful

Comment: what version is it now?

Comment: have no idea what you are using. Date on link is this month, video was I think in august. If intend to work with angular forms much, video is excellent ( angular team member). API wasn't 100% complete then

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular 1.2x and I created a directive to determine if the text contains the @ symbol.

```
.directive('noAt', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                if (/@/.test(viewValue)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('noAt', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('noAt', true);
                    return viewValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```